# Criando uma capa em LaTeX com figura

Tags: latex

Boa noite,

recentemente me mudei pra França e estou começando a ter que escrever relatórios aqui. Como no Brasil, irei utilizar o LaTeX para fazê-los, porém no Brasil eu tinha uma capa fornecida por um professor para relatórios e aqui eu tive que fazer na mão. Eu fiz assim no LaTeX:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\enlargethispage{\footskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{center}
\onehalfspacing
\large
BORDEAUX INP\\
ENSEIRB-MATMECA\\
2A 
\vspace{5mm}
\Large


\vspace{20mm}

\huge
\textbf{Compte-rendu : Commande d'un ascenseur par automate programmable}
\end{center}

\vspace{23mm}

\begin{center}
\centering
\onehalfspacing
\large
AUTEURS
\end{center}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedleft
\onehalfspacing
\large
\textit{}\\[.5\baselineskip]


\vspace{5mm}

\textit{}\\[.5\baselineskip]

\end{minipage}%

\vspace{\fill}

\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
\centering
\onehalfspacing
\large   
\today\\

\vspace{-20mm}
```

Porém gostaria de ter algo que tivesse o formato dessa capa fornecida por word por um colega de classe:

[image]

Alguém poderia me ajudar a fazer esse tipo de capa? Talvez a partir da capa que eu já fiz meio porcamente?

Comment: Que tal assim? https://www.dropbox.com/s/be4lg8p48rqrp2m/mono_final.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Pelo visto queres assim: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1s6n1tku2e45i6d/prova.pdf?dl=0